# Same function with same arguments, from same dll reference (same path, same file), working for one .NET project, but not for an other

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

The .NET project that works is on .NET framework 4.6.1. The one that does not work is on .NET framework 4.7.2.
This is the Function:

```
return DAL.DALGeneral.SelectScalar("GetYearName", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Year", year } }).ToString();
```

This is the Error message:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DAL.DALGeneral.GetConnectionString(String DataBase) +83
   DAL.DALGeneral.SelectScalar(String spName, Dictionary`2 parameters, String DataBase, String ConnectionString) +123
   OnlineYudGimelDaledSignIn.Models.LookUp.GetYearName(Int32 year) in C:\Users\giln\source\repos\OnlineYudGimelDaledSignIn\OnlineYudGimelDaledSignIn\Models\LookUp.cs:58
   OnlineYudGimelDaledSignIn.Site.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\giln\source\repos\OnlineYudGimelDaledSignIn\OnlineYudGimelDaledSignIn\Site.Master.cs:29
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +52
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +97
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +61
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +134
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +693
```

Im stumped as to why, the same function with the same arguments works from an other project.

I tried sending different arguments to the function and i get different error, but i need it to be these arguments.

Comment: Try check your connection string

Comment: The connection string is in the config file of the DAL dll application. so it should be the same  for both projects, but only work for one. Now that i think about it i don't understand how the dll file is accessing his config file.

Comment: Check the error message the exception ```DAL.DALGeneral.GetConnectionString(String DataBase) ```. Maybe check the database exist or not

Comment: You are right I had a missing connection string in the project config file. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i had a missing connection string in the web.config file in the second project. I didn't realize dll reference uses the current project config file, and not his own somehow.

Comment: That's just how it is. The app.config file of the DLL isn't used. Makes sense when you think about it, as each runnable project that consumes the DLL may need to configure things differently.